# How do I open a url that downloads a file in WebBrowser and saves the file (without being prompted about the path)?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

When I open a link that downloads a file in a WebBrowser, I'm asked to select the path to save the file. How can I do this automatically, i.e. save it in the path specified by me without being asked about it?

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
wb.Url = uri;
```

Comment: If you need to download the file without user interaction, why using the `WebBrowser` control in the first place? Just download the file programmatically using `HttpClient` and save it wherever you need.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma because of this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592480/download-file-with-webclient-but-data-is-incorrect

Comment: Still, there is **no good reason** to use `WebBrowser`. Also, I suggested you to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, and not `WebClient` (which are two completely different classes). Your issue stands on the other question, you should really solve that problem without opening a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Navigating` & `DownloadFileCompleted` events of `WebBrowser` control.  In the `Navigating` event, you can apply `If` condition to check file-type.

Visit [Open/Save WebBrowser Control Dialog Box](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d338a2c8-96df-4cb0-b8be-c5fbdd7c9202/opensave-webbrowser-control-dialog-box?forum=csharpgeneral) for example of downloading `zip` file.